# server.listen(5) vs multithreading in socket programming

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I am working on socket programming in python. I am a bit confused with the concept of s.listen(5) and multithreading.

As I know, s.listen(5) is used so that the server can listen upto 5 clients.

And multithreading is also used so that server can get connected to many clients.

Please explain me in which condition we do use multithreading?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use multithreading to handle multiple clients. When you accept a connection you receive a new socket instance that represents the connection with that new client. Now lets suppose you are making a chat and you need to receive the data from one client and send it to all connected clients, if you are not using multithreading you will need to implement a **non-performatic** logic using a single process loop to walk your connected clients reading each one and after all send to them the data, but you will have another problem because the listen function creates an IO interruption that waits until a new client try to connect if you don't use non-block socket. It's all about architecture, performance and good practices.

A good reading about multithreading follow this link https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-multiprocessing-and-multithreading.html.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is incorrect, as acknowledged later in the answer.

Comment: I want to write an algorithm in python file to create a csv file including the information (Ids, ip_add, mac_add) and a column to show the connection between devices in the network topology over a virtual environment .

I was thinking to use multithreading for every new client server connection(as there can be many clients connected to one server) and take out the ID no. to show in csv file. But I am not able to write the program for that.
Can you help me with that I can share my program?

Answer (score 0):

> As I know, s.listen(5) is used so that the server can listen upto 5 clients.

No. `s.listen(5)` declares a backlog of size 5. Than means that the listening socket will let 5 connection requests in pending stated before they are accepted. Each time a connection request is accepted it is no longer in the pending backlog. So there is no limit (other than the server resources) to the number of *accepted* connections.

A common use of multithreading is to start a new thread after a connection has been accepted to process that connection. An alternative is to use `select` on a single thread to process all the connections in the same thread. It used to be the rule before multithreading became common, but it can lead to more complex programs